# How to get hidden argument in python

Tags: python, r

See there's a piece of R code:

```
    loonPlotFactory <- function(factory_tclcmd, factory_path,   factory_window_title="loon plot", parent=NULL, ...)
```

And the three dots argument means there should be some hidden arguments or add arguments available afterwards.
So how to do this in python?
Is the package named *argparser* solve this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, python does support multiple arguments, from this link: https://www.learnpython.org/en/Multiple_Function_Arguments

You can get extra arguments in a list by using `*args`

```
def myFunction(first, second, third, *args):
    # function body
    # access extra args through: args[index]
```

Or in a dictionary by using `**kwargs`

```
def myFunction(first, second, third, **kwargs):
    # function body
    # access extra args through: kwargs["key"]
```

`*args` and `**kwargs` names are the python convention for grabbing extra/multiple arguments.

Comment: Note: by convention you would normally see `*args` and `**kwargs` (they can be named anything - but comprehension can be easier when using convention).